# Monitoring app switching on OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to know, from within a Swift application, when the user changes from one application to another, just in general.

For example: switching from Google Chrome to a different app like Xcode would trigger this event.

Is there any way to pick up application switching events, like through an event monitor perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add an observer on `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter` watching for the `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` key. You point the selector at one of your methods and grab the information from the `userInfo` dictionary.

Simple example in AppDelegate:

**Swift 2.2**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                                        selector: #selector(activated),
                                                        name: NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification,
                                                        object: nil)
}

func activated(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo,
        app = info[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey],
        name = app.localizedName {
            print(name)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                                        selector: #selector(activated(_:)),
                                                        name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplication,
                                                        object: nil)
}

func activated(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo,
        let app = info[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey] as? NSRunningApplication,
        let name = app.localizedName 
    {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 you need to use the keyword `let` for each optional binding. Also, the running application, as extracted from the userInfo dictionary, is of type `any`, and it needs to be further cast to the `NSRunningApplication` type.

So the Swift 3 answer given by Eric Aya works but needs small modifications:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                                        selector: #selector(activated),
                                                        name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplication,
                                                        object: nil)
}

func activated(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo,
        let app = info[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey] as? NSRunningApplication,
        let name = app.localizedName {
            print(name)
    }
}
```

(I would have left this post as comment to the accepted answer, but not enough rep...)