# Swift code to track last focused application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I know that `NSWorkspace` lets you launch applications from within your app. But I couldn't find anything there that could let me track which application was the last one before mine came to the foreground. I want to do this so that I can automatically switch back via some action. Is this possible with APIs or would I need some kind of secondary helper app for that?

Comment: You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411457/2227743) and keep track of the previous app received (after you already got a notification once).

Comment: Excellent! I do indeed get notified when switching between apps, even if my app is not up front. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: How do I give you credit @EricAya?

Comment: Ah, cool! I'm glad it's what you needed. I'm marking this question as duplicate of the other one, you have nothing specific to do. :)